# MS Access ignoring Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6 library

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am having serious problems with the Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 SP6 library in Access. I have a number of scripts which were working fine before the weekend, but which fail lately on multiple different computers when they encounter the StrConv function. Here's a low-down on what's been going on:

Previously, all was working fine. On the afternoon of Friday the 20th (4 days ago), I began encountering some odd messages when I moused over a progress bar ActiveX control I had on one of my forms. This happened on the MouseMove, MouseDown, MouseUp and MouseClick events at least; the message reported was "The expression [MouseMove] you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: There was an error loading an ActiveX control on one of your forms or reports." I had registered none of the events mentioned on this control. Scripts in general were still working at this point.

Yesterday (after the weekend), I found that scripts I had written no longer worked. When encountering the StrConv function (which I was using to convert a string to uppercase), the VBA editor brought up an error message saying "Compile error: Can't find project or library." This function I'd imagine is quite a core part of the VBA language, but the only missing library I could find under Tools->References was "Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)". The missing file was listed as C:\Windows\system32\MSCOMCTL.OCX but this was present on the machine anyway. Browsing to it in the references dialogue made no difference.

Since then I have tried installing various different Microsoft Visual Basic redistributions, have followed the instructions at http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/controls/mscomctl/, have phoned our company's tech support and have tried a system restore to a point where the scripts functioned previously, but nothing has worked. The database I am using resides in a networked folder on a server but the MS Access applications are local to the workstations.

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: is your windows 32 bit? is your office 32 bit?  Are they all 32 bit across entire network?

Comment: I agree with monster, the 64 bit of Office doesn't allow ActiveX at all. So either you will need to shift back to 32 bit of MsComCTL.ocx will need to be removed.

Comment: The machine I am currently using is 32-bit and it's having the MSCOMCTL problem. As for Office, I can only assume it's 32-bit since it does run on this computer. For the rest of the systems I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Simply open one of the forms giving you trouble in Design View. Insert a new ActiveX object control in the form and save. Load the forms again. Hopefully this solves the problem. You can then safely delete the added control.